# Can not read properties using Spring property holder

Tags: java, spring, properties, selenium-webdriver

I tried to use property file in my maven-java project for test automation.

This is the context.xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context ">

<util:properties id="properties" location="classpath:test-context.properties"/>

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="properties" ignore-unresolvable="false"/>


<bean id="settings" class="util.TestSettings">
    <property name="properties" ref="properties"/>
</bean>
```

These are my java classes.

```
import java.util.Properties;

public class TestSettings {

private static Properties properties;

public static String getProperty(String key) {
    return properties.getProperty(key);
}

public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
    TestSettings.properties = properties;
}
}
```

---

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:test-context.xml")
public class P_1_LoginPage extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

private P_1_LoginPage p1LoginPage;
private WebDriver driver;

public P_1_LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {

    this.driver = driver;

    driver.get(TestSettings.getProperty("base.url"));

}

@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void BeforeTest() throws MalformedURLException {

    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
    p1LoginPage = new P_1_LoginPage(driver);

}

public void assertThere() {

   //assert here
}
```

---

### update

here is my context.property file.

```
base.url=http://uname:pword@test.mysite.com.au/sdfdf
email.Queue.url=http://uname:pword@test.mysite.com.au/admin/admin/show_msgs
```

When I try to run test cases, it gives a null pointer exception here.

```
public static String getProperty(String key) {
    return properties.getProperty(key);
}
```

Can some one help me to figure out the issue here?

Comment: What is null in that function? The "properties" or does it just not find the value by the "key"?

Comment: @THarms : I am beginner in programming,I can not exactly find out it.But it shows in the "return properties.getProperty(key);" line.

I have mapped the property file, see the updated question. I think mapping value and key is correct.
Thanks

Comment: The complete way of using the properties in the test (with spring) is wrong. -- Sorry I have no time to describe in detail, because of a lack of time, but I hope this info helps you to search in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code breaks few Spring guidelines, like for example static field used to access properties, or creating `P_1_LoginPage` with new operator outside container. But the main problem for NullPointer is, that Spring context is not yet initialized in `@BeforeClass` (method should be static also, otherwise it will cause exception). Replace `@BeforeClass` with `@Before`.

Comment: Mikalas Thanks a lot.
As you mentioned issue was "Spring context is not yet initialized in BeforeClass ".Since It is a testng annotation I didn't use "Before".

What I did was, initializing Spring Context in the Test cases class and then it was fixed.